# Drag and Drop in position dropped jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have a tree drawn in [jqxtree](http://jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/index.htm). I have to drag the tree element and draw a small box div and append into div id `processFlowId`.

dragAndDrop code

```
$( ".dragItem" ).draggable({ revert: true,
         revertDuration: 0,
         cancel : 'span',
         refreshPositions: true 
        //,containment: "parent"
         ,helper: 'clone'});
$('#jqxTree').jqxTree({
       height: '200px',
       width: '300px',
       theme: 'energyblue',
       allowDrag: true,
       allowDrop: false
   });
 $(".dragItem").css({"position": ""});
var itemFlag =0;
$("#acceptDrop").droppable({
          accept: ".dragItem",
          activeClass: "drop-active",
          hoverClass: "drop-hover",
          drop: function (event, ui) {
              var itemid = ui.draggable.attr("id");
              itemFlag++
              drawAttrList(itemid + "_" + itemFlag,itemid,"processElement",ui);
          }
});
function drawAttrList(mainDivId, droppedToolId, dataMiningType,ui) {
    var html = '<div class="mouseHover" id="'+ mainDivId+ '"'
     + 'style="width:200px;"'+'><div class="widget-box w"><div class="widget-header" title="'+ mainDivId+ '">';
html += '<h4 class="lighter smaller" onclick="openProperties(\''
            + mainDivId + '\',\'' + dataMiningType
            + '\')"><i class="icon-random blue"></i>' + droppedToolId + '</h4>';
    html += '</div>';

    html += '<div  class="widget-body" ><div class="widget-main" ><div class="row-fluid">';

    html += '<div id="cart_toolbarList " class="drags"><div id="'+itemFlag+ droppedToolId + 'List_items" style="height:100px">';
    html += '<ul  class="item-list ui-sortable ' + droppedToolId + 'List'+ itemFlag + '" style="height:100%;border-style: dashed;border-width: 1px;border-color: silver;">';
    html += '</ul></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
    $("#" + mainDivId).draggable({
        revertDuration : 0,
        refreshPositions : true,
        revert: true,
        helper : 'clone'
    });
    $("#processFlowId").append(html);
}
```

Please refer my 
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srivaish/MAEvS/251/)

**Problem**

I need to drag the li and draw accordingly in the position where I dropped. Now it is not drawn in the position where we dropped.

Any suggestions to make this! 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the drop position, we use ui.position which will gives "top, left" relative to the offset element. i.e.,

```
var top = ui.position.top; // gives the top postion
var left = ui.position.left; // gives the left postion
```

Now append these x and y coordinates, to the small box div which is appended into div id "processFlowId", with the help of style attribute. Such as,

```
<div class="mouseHover" id="'+ mainDivId+ '"'+ 'style="width:200px;position:absolute; top: '+ top+ 'px; left: '+ left+ 'px;"'>
```

Check out the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/253/)